# Changes in job page of jenkins shows only first line from comments

Tags: git, svn, jenkins

When Jenkins job is built from git URL, job page "Changes" shows only first line of comment even-though it has many lines of comments. It has a option "detail" and if it is clicked it will show all the comments. why is it ? I want to show all the committed comments in "changes" page.This issue is only when I build project using git URL. In SVN,"changes" shows all the comments. Does anybody know how to resolve this issue.

[image: 4 commits in this image and it shows only first line comments of each commits] 4 commits in this image and it shows only first line comments of each commits

[image: when i clicked on detail it shows all the comments of the particular commit] when i clicked on detail it shows all the comments of the particular commit

Using testfairy plugin I am sending email to the testers by marking changelog as shown below,
[[image: click here for testfairy plugin image]]

But when testers get mail it shows only the comments as shown in "changes" job page.But I want all the comments not only the first line of comment

Comment: Maybe you can't. Write your commit messages such that the first line is useful (but short)

Comment: Yes if it is short line of comments it takes all. But I want all the comments to be shown.Because it is sent in email by testfairy plugin

Comment: Then *mention that*. Explain the actual problem you're trying to solve; context is useful!

Comment: FYI https://www.fullcontact.com/blog/git-commit-messages-testflight-jenkins/

Comment: Thank you. I have gone through the mentioned link,but it didn't help me out. _EnvInject_  plugin doesn't have the option for taking the commit message from git. And can you please tell me how this plugin helps for taking the comments. I am building android projects and using gradle wrapper to create apk file

Comment: Use the plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin
It solved my issue.